# windows.location = url breaks MVC binding

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on a javascript function which should redirect the user to a new page after getting certain data.

My example ilustrates the idea:

```
var userId = getUserId(e);
var url = baseUrl + "/EditUserRoles/" + userId;
window.location.href = url;
```

In my controller I have the following method:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult EditUserRoles(int userId)
    {
        return View(userId);
    }
```

If you put a breakpoint in the method it gets executed but the userId is always 0 regardless of the previous value on the javascript

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appens because your default route is waiting for id and  not userId

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

3 options, choose only one :

1 - Change id to userId in the MapRoute(I would not recommend it)

2 - Add userId url parameter in javascript

```
var url = baseUrl + "/EditUserRoles/?userId=" + userId;
```

3 - Change the name of the parameter to id in the controller

```
public IActionResult EditUserRoles(int id)
```

More Info : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs